# Tic Tac Toe Visual basic Not comparing Button Text correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to code a simple Tic tac toe with 9 buttons . 
When i click any of buttons i am shown a message box with a WIN dialog . Though this message box is meant to show only when a WIN CASE occurs . 
The problem is it that it is not comparing Button.Text values correctly.

Initially All button's TEXT property is empty .
On click i am setting their TEXT to "x" or "0" as the case maybe . 
This is suppose to work correctly but cant figure why it is not comparing the newly assigned TEXT of `clicked` button with other Button's Text.

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim count As Int32 = 0
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub
Sub checkwin()
    If Button1.Text = Button2.Text And Button2.Text = Button3.Text Then

        MessageBox.Show(Button1.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()


    ElseIf Button4.Text = Button5.Text And Button5.Text = Button6.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button4.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()

    ElseIf Button7.Text = Button8.Text And Button8.Text = Button9.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button7.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()
    ElseIf Button1.Text = Button4.Text And Button4.Text = Button7.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button1.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()

    ElseIf Button2.Text = Button5.Text And Button5.Text = Button8.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button2.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()
    ElseIf Button3.Text = Button6.Text And Button6.Text = Button9.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button3.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()
    ElseIf Button1.Text = Button5.Text And Button5.Text = Button9.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button1.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()

    ElseIf Button3.Text = Button5.Text And Button5.Text = Button7.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show(Button3.Text & "wins")
        Call reset()
    End If

End Sub


Sub reset()
   For Each b as Button  in Controls

        b.Text = " "
        b.Enabled = True

    Next


End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click
    If sender Is Button1 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button1.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button1.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button2 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button2.Text = "0"
        Else
            Button2.Text = "x"
        End If


        Button2.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button3 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button3.Text = "0"
        Else
            Button3.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button3.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()


    End If
    If sender Is Button4 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button4.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button4.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button4.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If
    If sender Is Button5 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button5.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button5.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button5.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button6 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button6.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button6.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button6.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button7 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button7.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button7.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button7.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button8 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button8.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button8.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button8.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If

    If sender Is Button9 Then
        count = count + 1
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Button9.Text = "0"

        Else
            Button9.Text = "x"
        End If

        Button9.Enabled = False
        Call checkwin()
    End If



End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not eliminating unused buttons in the `checkWin` sub's `If` statements. You should also use short-circuiting comparisons to avoid unnecessary processing. So, the first `If` statement would look like this:

```
If Not Button1.Enabled AndAlso Not Button2.Enabled AndAlso Not Button3.Enabled AndAlso _
            (Button1.Text = Button2.Text) AndAlso (Button2.Text = Button3.Text) Then
    ...
ElseIf Not Button4.Enabled ... 'etc.
```

Oh and all those `If` blocks in your button click event are unnecessary. Just use the sender object, like so:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click,
            Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click
    sender.Text = If(clickCount Mod 2 = 0, "X", "O")
    sender.Enabled = False
    clickCount += 1
    CheckWin()
End Sub
```

**Edit** (requested in comments)
To avoid the repetitive comparison code in the CheckWin sub, you can farm out the work to a function. That way the comparison code is only written once and consequently far less prone to errors and much easier to read. Something like this is what I would do:

```
Private Sub CheckWin()
    If LineWins(Button1, Button2, Button3) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button4, Button5, Button6) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button7, Button8, Button9) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button1, Button4, Button7) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button2, Button5, Button8) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button3, Button6, Button9) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button1, Button5, Button9) OrElse _
       LineWins(Button3, Button5, Button7) Then ResetGame()
End Sub

Private Function LineWins(b1 As Button, b2 As Button, b3 As Button) As Boolean
    LineWins = CBool(Not b1.Enabled AndAlso Not b2.Enabled AndAlso Not b3.Enabled _
                 AndAlso (b1.Text = b2.Text) AndAlso (b2.Text = b3.Text))
    If LineWins Then MessageBox.Show(b1.Text & " wins")
End Function
```

By the way, you may notice I've renamed "reset" to "ResetGame" – I recommend you do this as [`Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.reset.aspx) is already assigned to a .NET `FileSystem` method.

Comment: Excellent ! Just never used OO so will try to learn it step by step. Also checkwin() can simply be called  as u wrote ,so y does VB has explicit keyword `Calls`

Comment: I have few more queries 1.Can i use `And` instead of `AndAlso`  2. Where exactly we short circuited the comparisions ?

Comment: @kushal `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are short-circuiting operators because unlike `And` and `Or` they don't evaluate the subsequent parts of the statement if the current comparison evaluates to `True.`

Comment: BTW, you should also consider avoiding the repetitive comparison code in the checkWin sub by writing a function to which you pass the three buttons to compare as parameters.

Comment: Can u Please edit ur post further to implement checkwin the way u recommending . It will be of great help !!

Comment: @kushal I've edited my answer to show you what I mean. I hope this gives you a good understanding of how to approach problems like this in future.